# ASIO drivers on Windows 10 IOT on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: windows, windows-10-iot-core, asio

I am writing an application that processes audio intented to run on Windows 10 IOT. I want to use ASIO drivers, because of performance. The Asio4all drivers cannot be installed. 
Is there (already) a Windows 10 IOT Asio driver that i don't know of?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's kind of your Windows 10 IOT device?

Comment: I want to run it on the Raspberry pi (3). This one: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48233

Comment: As far as I know, there is no ASIO driver for Windows 10 IoT on ARM device like Raspberry Pi.